# javadoc for package-info.java only

Tags: java, maven-2, javadoc, package

I have a situation where I'd like to execute javadoc in a project that has no classes. It only has package-info.java for one package. When executing javadoc, the following error is given:

```
An error has occurred in JavaDocs report generation:Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - No public or protected classes found to document.
```

Is there any way to force it to process package-info.java only (aside from the obvious hacky solutions: creating a dummy class, scripting the copying of a package.html, etc.)?

I'm executing javadoc as part of a maven build, so the maven-javadoc-plugin is performing the actual javadoc command.

Comment: If there are no classes, why do you need the package javadoc?

Comment: I'm using a tool (specifically enunciate) that uses package doc as the means to customize "splash" doc for a larger site that it generates.

Comment: More specifically, why does the package exist if it doesn't contain anything?

Comment: I answered that above. I'm using a tool that generates a site documenting services, and the means to customize part of the doc is to supply a java package containing the extra content in its package doc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There isn't a way to get JavaDoc to run on an empty package. There is a really old bug ([JDK-4492654](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-4492654)) posted for this marked as "Closed, Will Not Fix".

In that bug the workaround is pretty much the obvious hacky one you mention, create a default-scoped empty class. The class won't be included in the javadoc unless you force it to be with -package or -private.

```
/** hack to generate package javadoc */
class PlaceHolder {}
```

Comment: Note that your placeholder java class file must have at least one /** */ comment, otherwise the workaround won't work around the problem.

Comment: But with a default scoped class, the javadoc generation still gives the error described in the question, you need a public class no ? And there is no way to generate javadoc for a package without having at least one documented class ?